# advent of code day 1 2023 problem my own way

Tags: python, math, sum

I have been trying to figure out advent of code 2023 day 1 for a while and im REALLY close, i just can't seem to get the sum of the numbers on my list. for reference, 'ref' is the file where the input is stored and 'adding' is where numbers are turned into a list, which is kind of an unnecessary step come to think of it since im doing it at the bottom.

speaking of which, the bottom is what im trying to figure out. when i print 'total' i just get "1" and nothing else, not sure what im doing wrong. i am very aware there are more conventional ways to do this but i wanted to figure it out myself without looking up a guide and i know im really close, so if anyone can help me figure out why the list at the end isnt adding together correctly with sum() that would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

```
with open('ref', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        digits = [char for char in line.strip() if char.isdigit()]
        first = digits[int()]
        factor = 10
        result = []
        for ele in first:
            result.append(ele * factor)
        length = len(digits)
        last = digits[length - 1]
        endnum = first + last
        if length == 1:
            endnum = (first)
        else:
            pass
        with open('adding', 'a') as f:
            f.writelines(str(endnum + ','))

file = open('adding', 'r')
x = []
total = 0
for i in file:
    x.append(i)
    y = sum([(i in x) for i in x])
    total += int(y)
    print(total)
```

Day 1 problem description: https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/1

The problem statement (irrelevant wording omitted):

> The file consists of lines of text; on each line, the value can be found by combining the first digit and the last digit to form a single two-digit number.
> For example:

```
1abc2
pqr3stu8vwx
a1b2c3d4e5f
treb7uchet
```

> In this example, the  values of these four lines are 12, 38, 15, and 77. Adding these together produces 142.
> Consider your entire file. What is the sum of all of the values?

Comment: We don't know what the AoC task is. Please explain what this is supposed to be doing.

Comment: `digits[int()]` would be more clearly written as `digits[0]`

Comment: @smac89 The description should be in the question, not a link.

Comment: And `digits[length - 1]` can be just `digits[-1]`. In Python, negative indexes count from the end.

Comment: Why are you using `writelines()` instead of `write()`? `writelines()` should be used when `endnum` is a list of strings, not a single string.

Comment: Why do you need to write the numbers to a file in the first place? Just add it to a `total` variable in the first loop.

Comment: `print(total)` shouldn't be in the loop, just at the end.

Comment: You never use the variable `result`. You could delete all the lines which deal with `result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The issue

The problem is that you do not add any line breaks to the `adding` file. I.e. the contents of the file looks something like:

```
45,12,34,
```

Therefore, when you do something like:

```
for i in file:
    x.append(i)
```

(*Note that `for i in file` reads the file one line at a time.*)

After the first iteration, the entire file has been read and `x` will contain a list which looks like:

```
['45,12,34,']
```

Now in that same loop, when you do:

```
y = sum([(i in x) for i in x])
total += int(y)
```

You're actually just doing:

```
y = sum([True]) # == 1
total += int(y)
```

because `(i in x)` returns True, and since there is only one element in the list, you end up with a list of a single `True`.

Hence why your `total` is always `1`.

#### Solution

The simplest solution I can suggest is to split the first element of your list `x`, by `,`, convert to int, and add up all the numbers:

```
total = sum(map(int, x[0].strip(',').split(',')))
```

To break it down:

- `x[0].strip(',')` will remove the trailing `comma` from the string
- `x[0].strip(',').split(',')` will split the rest of the strings to create a list of numeric strings (`isnumeric()`)
- `map(int, ...)` converts each string to an int
- `sum(...)` returns the sum of all the ints

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct, but you need to learn some idioms that make Python programming a real joy. Consider:

```
result = 0
# the total is zero

with open(...) as fp:
    
    for line in fp:
        # iterate line by line
    
        digits = [char for char in line if char.isdigit()]
        # that's fine, but you don't need strip
        
        number = digits[0] + digits[-1]
        # -1 means "last". Note this works just fine if there's only one digit
        
        result += int(number)
        # convert to int and add

print(result)
# that's all
```

On a general note, trying to do things "your way" is rarely productive. Programming is like chess; you learn by watching good players and trying to understand what they do. Blindly moving pieces around won't get you anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop is calculating a running total in `y`, and then adding that each time to `total`. This is effectively multiplying each number by the number of following lines.

There's no need to calculate the total twice like that. You can just use the built-in `sum()` function to sum all the numbers in the file.

```
with open('adding') as file:
    total = sum(int(line) for line in file)

print(total)
```